# Bundler Version issue is coming in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been working with Ruby On Rails since a long. Currently I made an application and trying to deploy via **AWS ElasticBeanstalk**, in this I tried to fix some issues while deploying. But currently I am facing issue in **Bundler versions** with the following error.

```
Bundler version 1.5.1 is required; you're currently running 1.2.1. Maybe try `gem install bundler -v 1.5.2`.
```

[image]

I did the same thing as suggested `gem install bundler -v 1.5.2` and it is very clear to me that I am using the same version of bundler, but still it is raising the same issue as above even I pushed the new changes and restarting the EB server.

Comment: Run `gem list bundle` and check if it is showing the correct version of bundler.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I did the same as you suggested. The result was as below.
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.5.2, 1.5.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)